# Laravel eloquent sum and count within a query for nested relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

**Background**

I have 4 tables that have nested relationships with each other.

```
events 
contests (foreign key: evt_id)  
entries (foreign key: con_id) 
entry_winner (foreign key: ent_id)
```

I was able to get records with relations like this from the **Entry** model.

```
$accepted = Entry::where("is_canceled", "=", "0")
            ->with(["contest.event", "entryWinner"])
            ->whereHas("contest.event", function($query) {
                $query->where('datetime_utc', ">",Carbon::today());
            })
            ->has("entryWinner")
            ->get();
```

So far so good.

**PROBLEM**

What I want to get from the query is two things within a query.

1. Total number of records (count)
2. Total sum of relation table's column. (sum)

Here's a query that works exactly for me.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS accepted,
    SUM(contests.ent_fee) AS funds
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN contests ON contests.id = entries.con_id
RIGHT JOIN `events` ON `events`.id = contests.evt_id AND `events`.datetime_utc > '2019-11-22 00:00:00'
RIGHT JOIN entry_winners ON entry_winners.ent_id = entries.id
WHERE is_canceled = 0;
```

I'm just curious **how to achieve this using Eloquent**.

> How to use SUM and COUNT at once ??

Comment: I think you cannot get `sum` or `count` inside `with()` and then get it out to parents column by Eloquent. So just use `Model::leftjoin()` to get that.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$query = Entry::where("is_canceled", "=", "0")
            ->with(["entryWinner", "contest" => function($query) {
                $query->whereHas("event", function($qry) {
                    $qry->where('datetime_utc', ">",Carbon::today());
                })->sum('ent_fee');
            }])
            ->has("entryWinner");
$count = $query->count();
$results = array_column($query->get()->toArray(), 'contest');
$sum = array_sum(array_column($results, 'ent_fee'));
```

It should work and help you.

Comment: I got this error : Unknown column 'contest.ent_fee' in 'field list'

Comment: Try with `contests.ent_fee`.

Comment: I got the same error, after some research I noticed that I can't use related db columns with DB::raw.

Comment: I have updated the answer to resolving the column related issues. This is logic you can proceed with.

Comment: If still facing an issue with the updated solution, Then I would suggest you use `DB::raw("Your SQL query goes here")`. It's not always best practice though.